# Strsplit error parsing JSON using RJSON

Tags: json, r, strsplit, rjson

I've got a well formated JSON string with a R script, but when I try to parse it using the rjson package (with parser$addData), I get this error :

```
>json <- fromJSON(docret)

>parser <- newJSONParser()
>parser$addData(json)

Erreur dans strsplit(buf, "") : 
  l'argument n'est pas une chaîne de caractères
```

My JSON string (docret here) is validated by two online JSON validators.
Can I do something about this error to have my JSON object usable?

Here is my JSON : 
http://shrib.com/8dTgq90U

Comment: I believe your variable `json` contains already parsed data (nested lists), hence there is no need to call `addData`.

Comment: That was it, I didn't understood that it was either using json<-fromJSON(docret) or parser$addData(docret) and then parser$getObject().
Meanwhile using fromJSON seems really faster than the other way.
Thanks for your answer!